# how to get toggle value from toggler in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

how to get particular column value from toggler event using primefaces

systemResult.xhtml

```
<p:row>
                    <p:column toggleId="usep" id="energyUsep" columnIndexVar="index" name="usep" headerText="USEP" filterBy="#{searchResult.energyUSEP}" visible="true"
                        filterMatchMode="exact" filterStyle="display:none" />
                    <p:column headerText="Energy Requirement"
                        filterBy="#{searchResult.energyRequirement}"
                        filterMatchMode="exact" filterStyle="display:none" />
                </p:row>
```

systemResultBeanManaged.java

```
public void onToggle(final ToggleEvent e) {
    System.out.println("check doggler method");

    //String toggleId = e.getToggleId().toString();
    System.out.println();
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();   
    Map<String,String> requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();   

    System.out.println("client id:-");
    System.out.println(e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("name")); // j_idt109 - USEP

    System.out.println("ToggleId: " + e.getComponent().getValueBinding("toggleId") + "Visibity Name: "
            + e.getVisibility().name()); // "", "Status:" + );
    System.out.println("component id:"+e.getComponent().getId());

    String val=e.getData().toString();
    System.out.println("column value:"+val);
    String usep = e.getData().toString();
    String energy = e.getData().toString();
    System.out.println("energy:" + energy);
    System.out.println("usep:" + usep);
}
```

Comment: toggle what? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: You get it with `e.getData()`, but that is already in your question.. so, what's not working for you?